# Free disk space isn't reducing when bfiles are added

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle database version 12c. For bulk data testing I need to insert at least 1 TB of data. Now the problem is that after inserting data in a table, free space on disk is not decreasing. I followed these steps.

1) created table space (If things works I want to create 100 tablespaces having 10 GB capacity. Note that I have E: drive having 1.26 TB space)

```
create tablespace tbls1
datafile E:\app\User1\oradata\BulkData\mydata.dbf'
size 10000m;
```

2) created table using tablespace tbls1.

```
create table graphics_table (
  bfile_id number,
  bfile_desc varchar2(30),
  bfile_loc bfile,
  bfile_type varchar2(4))
  TABLESPACE tbls2
  storage (initial 1m next 1m pctincrease 0)
```

3) performed insert operation in a loop using a 4 MB JPEG file.

```
DECLARE
  k integer:= 1;
BEGIN
  << super_outer_loop >>
  FOR k IN 1..2500 LOOP 
        INSERT INTO graphics_table
        VALUES(k,'wallpaper i have',bfilename('JPEG_FILES','WALLPAPER.JPEG'),'JPEG');
  END loop super_outer_loop;  
END;
```

Now if I check the size of my E: drive, it shows only 1 GB used. If I run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GRAPHICS_TABLE` it is giving me correct count.

Please help me understand why disk space isn't being consumed.

Answer (score 3):

Another name for `BFILE` is *external LOB*. As the name suggests, the actual data remains external to the database, and only a link to the file is stored in the table. In your test you insert 2500 links to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create your table as:

```
create table graphics_table (
  bfile_id number,
  bfile_desc varchar2(30),
  bfile_loc bfile,
  bfile_type varchar2(4))
  TABLESPACE tbls2
  storage (initial 1t next 1g pctincrease 0)
```

That should allocate about a TB to GRAPHICS_TABLE.